# XCode project outdated in release mode

Tags: ios, xcode

When i'm switching from debug mode to release mode, I see an outdated version of application. E.g. i've changed some buttons in source code, if i'm running debug mode, i see changed buttons. If i'm running release - i don't see any changes.
I've tried to `Clean`, `Window > Projects > Delete`, reboot simulator, reboot xcode etc. Nothing helps.

Comment: Look at base SDK in project/target settings

Comment: i've found it, what exactly should i look at?

Comment: the root of this issue is located somewhere out of the project's folder. I've just deleted an entire folder and git cloned repo again. And again i have the same issue. Also, i've moved to another location, and cloned repo there. In this case everything works fine - i have the latest code in release mode